# Trying to find nearest polygon of a point and returning error: Cast to number failed for value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

So I'm trying to do a $near query with mongoose, and this is returning an error that I cannot debug:

I want to find the nearest MultiPolygon of a Point

May someone please help me find a solution?

The returning error:

```
(node:1968) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
(node:1968) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to number failed for value "{
  val: -46.297337,
  context: Query {
    _mongooseOptions: {},
    _transforms: [],
    _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
    _executionCount: 1,
(...)
```

My controller function:

```
  async show(req, res) {
    const { lat, lng } = req.body;
    const pdv = await Pdv.find({
      coverageArea: {
        $near: {
          $geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: { lng, lat },
          },
        },
      },
    });
    return res.json(pdv);
  }
```

My Schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const PdvSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    coverageArea: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['MultiPolygon'],
        required: true,
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [[[[Number]]]],
        required: true,
      },
    },
    address: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Point'],
        required: true,
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        required: true,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

PdvSchema.index({ address: '2dsphere' });
PdvSchema.index({ coverageArea: '2dsphere' });

export default mongoose.model('Pdv', PdvSchema);
```